How reactive val works in Shiny
I am new to shiny. And hence wanted to understand how reactiveVal works and I came up with below sample application.
Here I have created a reactive value object y. So whenever a value of y changes as per RHS, it should get updated.
But in this sample, the output I get is 61 instead of 90. Can anyone explain why this is happening

library(shiny)

# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- fluidPage(

    # Application title
    # titlePanel("Old Faithful Geyser Data"),

    # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins 
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(),

        # Show a plot of the generated distribution
        mainPanel(
           textOutput("text")
        )
    )
)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output) {

    
    output$text <- renderText({
      y <- reactiveVal(0)
      #x <- reactiveVal(0)
      x = 61
      y = x
      x = 90
      y
    })
    
  
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)


This has got nothing to do with reactiveVal() - you get the same result running the same code normally. I forget the terminology, but y = x copies the value of x to y but doesn't link them permanently, so x = 90 has no effect on y.

Thanks. Can you provide me a sample example on how it works. The output I am expecting is 90

You could define y as a reactive function of x:
library(shiny)

# Define UI
ui <- fluidPage(
  
  # Application title
  # titlePanel("Old Faithful Geyser Data"),
  
  # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins 
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(),
    
    # Show a plot of the generated distribution
    mainPanel(
      textOutput("text")
    )
  )
)

# Define server logic
server <- function(input, output) {
 
  x <- reactiveVal(0)
  y <- reactive(x())

  output$text <- renderText({
   
    x(61)
    x(90) 
    y()

  })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)

Note that assignment of a value to x, which is a reactiveVal function, is done by passing the new value as argument.

@rakshu vin, did it answer your question?

You have to pass x in reactiveVal not zero.
library(shiny)

# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- fluidPage(
  
  # Application title
  # titlePanel("Old Faithful Geyser Data"),
  
  # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins 
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(),
    
    # Show a plot of the generated distribution
    mainPanel(
      textOutput("text")
    )
  )
)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output) {
  
  
  output$text <- renderText({
    y <- reactiveVal(x)
    #x <- reactiveVal(0)
    x = 61
    y = x
    x = 90

  })
  
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)

